# Salesforce Guest user access to Docusign Apex Toolkit to send an email

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

I am using the Docusign Apex Toolkit in Salesforce to send emails as outlined here:
https://developers.docusign.com/salesforce/code-examples/salesforce-sending-signing-template

The email is sent when a case field is updated to a specific value via a trigger.

This works perfectly if I am a signed in user. However, if the user doing this is a guest then the following error is thrown:
You must have DocuSign sender permissions to perform this operation

Class.dfsle.Permissions.verifyIsDocuSignSender: line 300, column 1↵Class.dfsle.Permissions.verifyIsDocuSignSender: line 295

As this is the guest user I am unable to assign the permission sets to them as there is no user.

I have given permissions to all dosusign objects and fields to the guest user profile.

How can I allow emails to be sent automatically via apex in a trigger for guest users?

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign envelope can be created only by users who have DS Account and have atleast a Sender permission. It is like GMAIL, you will be able to send an email from GMAIL domain if you are a GMAIL user.

So in case of the Guest user, they will come to your App but your App should make DS API call to DocuSign with any System user credentials (like apiuser@system.com) who is a user in your DS Account. [Auth Type Doc](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication) explains this type of flow.

Comment: Thanks Amit, with the Docusign Apex Toolkit I don't think I can control that. From your comment and link it seems like your suggesting building a direct integration between Salesforce and docusign instead of using the appexchange package which contains the ready to go integration:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FK9gtUAD